# Linear-gradient - Make A Dashed Vertical Line

Tags: css, linear-gradients

So, I've looked all over and tried a couple of things, but I am just trying to create a dashed vertical line.  Similar to if you did border dashed.

Closes I got:

```
background: linear-gradient(transparent, #ffffff) no-repeat 80%/2px 100%, linear-gradient(#000, #000) no-repeat 80%/2px 100%;
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m9wtrdgz/

And yes I want the line at the 80% location ;]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for a `repeating-linear-gradient`:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0 4px,black 4px 8px) 80%/2px 100% no-repeat;
}
```

And if you want a fading color you can combine with a linear-gradient:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0 4px,#fff 4px 8px),
    linear-gradient(to bottom,black,transparent);
  background-size:2px 100%;
  background-position:80%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the location in the gradient to create the dashed line and then position the element containing the line in the location you want.

In this case, I used a `pseudo` element as the line "container" and positioned it absolutely 80% from the left edge.

Change the element size (width/height) to modify the line width.

The `background-size` changes the dash size/spacing

```css
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.content:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:70%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #000 75%, transparent 75%, transparent 100%);
  background-size: 10px 1px;
}
.content:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:80%;
  bottom:0;
  width: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, orange, orange 75%, transparent 75%, transparent 100%);
  background-size: 1px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  :before = horizontal line<br />
  :after = vertical line
</div>
```